# difference between eureka ID and service ID in spring cloud app?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I am reading through the [documentation](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html) on enabling `ZuulProxy` for spring cloud applications.

It starts as the following:

`By convention, a service with the Eureka ID "users", will receive requests from the proxy located at /users`

Then later down the documentation, it goes as following

```
To get more fine-grained control over a route you can specify the path and the serviceId independently:

application.yml
 zuul:
  routes:
    users:
      path: /myusers/**
      serviceId: users_service
This means that http calls to "/myusers" get forwarded to the "users_service" service. The route has to have a "path" which can be specified as an ant-style pattern, so "/myusers/*" only matches one level, but "/myusers/**" matches hierarchically.
```

here serviceID is referred. I am confused now? what is `users` and `users_service` in the above `application.yml`.

As far my understanding goes, every microservice application registers with Eureka provides a name as following in `bootstrap.yml`: For example,

```
spring:
  application:
    name: user
```

my understanding is that `user` is now Eureka ID as well as service ID. so what does `users` and `users_service` in the above mean?

Answer (score 2):

> By convention, a service with the Eureka ID "users", will receive requests from the proxy located at /users

In that context, `Eureka ID` refers to `service ID` - both terms are used through the documentation.

By default `spring.application.name` is used for the initial value of the `eureka ID` in the Eureka client.

Conclusion: yes, you are right in your understanding.

Comment: my question is what is  `users` and `users_sevice` in the application.yml described above. where are they configured?

Comment: `zuul.routes.users` is the serviceId UNLESS, there is a `serviceId` attribute. Otherwise it's just a key in a map.